# How does heroku with buildpacks handle PATH?

Tags: r, heroku, environment-variables, buildpack

I'm using the [heroku-buildpack-r](https://github.com/virtualstaticvoid/heroku-buildpack-r) and heroku-buildpack-ruby in concert with heroku-buildpack-multi.  Everything installs correctly and R works locally.

```
# .buildpacks
https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-ruby.git
https://github.com/virtualstaticvoid/heroku-buildpack-r.git
```

According to [this heroku post](https://blog.heroku.com/archives/2012/11/13/hacking-buildpacks), the environment is set for buildpacks by the YAML in bin/release:

```
cat <<EOF
---
config_vars:
  PATH: /app/vendor/R/bin:bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
  R_HOME: /app/vendor/R
  R_INCLUDE: /app/vendor/R/lib64/R/include
EOF
```

This piece of code seems to run:

```
R 2.15.1 successfully installed
Using release configuration from last framework R:
---
config_vars:
  PATH: /app/vendor/R/bin:bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
  R_HOME: /app/vendor/R
  R_INCLUDE: /app/vendor/R/lib64/R/include
```

However, the path is not set to this following completion of the push:

```
~ $ echo $PATH
/app/bin:/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
```

I can set the PATH manually with `heroku config:set` which seems to be the only solution.

Why doesn't the buildpack set the path as advertised?

Answer (score 1):

Using a `.profile.d` script to set the environment variables seems to solve the problem when using with other buildpacks. You can use the [fixes](https://github.com/virtualstaticvoid/heroku-buildpack-r/tree/fixes) branch to try it out.

Answer (score 0):

Enable labs user-env-compile feature. 
This will make sure you have access to environment variables during compilation
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/labs-user-env-compile#enabling

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  This doesn't fix the problem, though.  This makes the environment available during slug compilation.  My problem is that during the *buildpack* compilation, certain ENV variables are supposed to be set that are not.

Answer (score 0):

I hit a very similar issue when wiring together R and Python via Heroku.  The trick is that the $PATH variable is reset for each buildpack as it is being run; the process is transactionalized per pack, and references a PATH that is not your heroku config:get PATH.  I do not know why.  You can make it work by forking the Heroku buildpack and explicitly adding on to the $PATH variable there.  I hear you might be able to set up the "true" buildpack repo as an upstream of your change, making all future changes pass through, but I have only forked and mangled to get things going myself.

Bonus round: you are probably going to hit problems even after this $PATH change as R complains about not being able to find things.  You need to add some specific .so's to your LD_LIBRARY_PATH (this time, the actual heroku config var).  Hope that helps!

Comment: That makes sense, except that the linked Heroku blog post says that precisely this should be possible.

Comment: I do not know what Heroku's position is, only what I was able to do to get it working.